# How would i rank my keywords in Yahoo search engine?

Tags: seo, yahoo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)

I am working as search engine optimizer team lead in a company and facing problem in a project which name is http://www.Prooftech.com.sg...

Problem :-

The Website has 10 keywords for which my client wanted the top 10 Ranking in Yahoo Singapore search engine.

I have got top 10 ranking for the following 7 keywords Waterproofing, RC Roof ,Wall Leakages ,Ceiling Leakages , Water Leakages ,Roof Tile Coating ,Roof Tiles Repair in my 3 months work but still i am not getting the listing positions for Roof ,Concrete Repair ,Grouting ....

I have Done lot of Bookmarking ,Blog Commenting ,Blog Creations ,Press Release,Classified Ads to get these 3 keywords in listing but there is no changes in the results....

Can any help me out from this problem so i can get Good rankings for Roof ,Concrete Repair ,Grouting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll just have to stick with the backlinking, see what prs and backlinks the other sites in the top 10 for those words have.

Also you might find the word"roof" just to broad a phrase, try ranking for somthing like roof repair, roof maintainence, roof fitting, roof installation ect as more long tail phrases

Comment: Ranking for "roof" would be like ranking for "Smith" in America. There's so darn many of them. "Smith & Wesson" narrows it a bit.

Comment: Thanks for this reply,Is there any more things by which we can get my results fast?

Comment: not really, fast and SEO just dont go together, the only way you can get reseults today is buy running some ppc ads